# Adding Entry to Pandas Dataframe as Column Instead of Row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, append

I am webscraping housing data and putting it into a pandas dataframe. I wanted to test my function for one listing before continuing on several. My only problem is the way the entry is being added to the dataframe.

[image]

The listing information is being added as a column instead of a row (I want it added as a row). Here is what I am doing. Is there a better function to use? Thanks in advance!

```
entry = pd.DataFrame([location, price, beds, baths, sqft, lotSize, neighborhoodMed, dom, built, 
          garage, neighborhood, hType, basementSize])

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["Address", "Price", "Beds", "Baths", "SqFt", "LotSize", 
                                 "NeighborhoodMedian", "DOM", "Built", "Garage", 
                                "Neighborhood", "Type", "BasementSize"])
df = pd.concat([df, entry])
```

Side note: location, price, beds, etc. are all values.
(e.g., a location could be `123 Main St`, a price could be `495,000`, etc.)

Comment: What is location, price beds, bath, etc.? are they lists?

Comment: @It_is_Chris Side note: location, price, beds, etc. are all values. (e.g., a location could be 123 Main St, a price could be 495,000, etc.)

Comment: Try making them a list of variables: `pd.DataFrame([[location, price, beds, bath . . . ]])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to convert 'entry' to a dictionary rather than a df and then use `df.append`:

```
entry_dict = {'Address': location,
              'Price': price,
              [...]
             }

df = df.append(entry_dict, ignore_index = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to this is to call `df.iloc[new_row's_index] = [address_value, price_value,...]`
You can follow the same pattern with `.loc` as long as you index by what the name of the row is, and not the index position (though it appears to be the same in your case)